# Prevent access to files in a certain folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a folder with a lot of `.php` files. I would like to deny access to them (using `.htaccess`). I know an option is to move this folder outside `public_html`, but this is not possible in this situation.

Is is possible to block access to a whole folder?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add this to the `.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this: <directory /template>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
</directory> but I'm getting a misconfiguration error :(

Comment: You must not use <directory>...</directory> in a .htaccess file. Just put the two lines above in the .htaccess.

Answer (score 26):

Apache 2.4 now uses a different way to do this so the method that works for Apache 2.2 will not work. See below for the method that will work for Apache 2.4. Place this in your Apache .htaccess file or better yet in a `<Directory>` directive in the Apache .conf file for your site.

**Using .htaccess:**

If using Apache 2.2:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

If using Apache 2.4 use:

```
Require all denied
```

**Using Apache Configuration files:**

Instead of using a .htaccess file, it is usually preferred to place the configuration directly in your Apache .conf file as follows:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mysite">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Or if using a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ### Other configuration here ###
    <Directory "/var/www/mysite">
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    ### Other configuration here ###
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course the above configurations are examples, and you will need to adjust according to your requirements.

Comment: Note, if this doesn't work, make sure that you haven't tweaked the `AllowOverride` parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161758/htaccess-deny-from-all-doesnt-work

Comment: example of how to use `<Directory>` would make this a better answer

Comment: @billynoah The OP was looking for specifically for .htaccess so was focusing mainly on that. Nonetheless, I have expanded my answer in case it is useful to someone else.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, just wanted to suggest adding that for benefit of others

Answer (score 7):

1. Create .htaccess file inside the desired folder with the following contents:

   `Deny from all`
2. Edit `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`, whatever you find in Apache2 directory (probably located in `/etc/apache2`). You'll need to edit/check the following:

   `AllowOverride ALL` (in the related <Directory> tag)

   `AccessFileName .htaccess`
3. Edit your site's configuration file only in case you have a <Directory> tag specified inside it and add the following line:

   `AllowOverride ALL`
4. Restart your Apache2 server

   `service apache2 restart`

The above steps are all meant for Linux environments. The same instructions would work well for Windows environments except for the paths and the server restart command.

Reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-htaccess/

Answer (score 5):

Just add a .htaccess file with the code `Deny from all` to the folder.

More info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html