# .htaccess deny from all doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my problem is that I want to deny the access to a folder but I can't.
I've put a `.htaccess` file in this folder with just these lines:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Any idea of what can be happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I get it! It was due to the apache configuration. In my `foo.conf` of sites-avaiables directory I had:

```
AllowOverride None
```

As apache doc says, *AllowOverride Description: Types of directives that are allowed in .htaccess files*

When it is changed to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

it works perfectly!
You can also configure it with specific options:

```
AllowOverride directive-type
```

directive-options at: [apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using that method. Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foldername
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.222\.333\.44$
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

With this method you need to add your own ip.

Options: instead of the last line being a 404 page not found:

```
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

you can change it to a 403 forbidden:

```
RewriteRule .*? - [F]
```

or redirect to your homepage:

```
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: Neither works. I think there is a problem with .htaccess reading or something like this, because there isn't any .htaccess working. I forgot to say that I'm working on my localhost (maybe it's important). It's working right on the server (http://itransformer.es)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do two things,first, change the conf of apache to allow override, 
second, to change the conf of a hosting to allow override

**first**

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to;

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Second**

```
   cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
   nano  yourdomain.com.conf
```

add the following codes into it,

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/yourdomain.com/public_html">
     AllowOverride All 
     Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

after adding

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin support@yourdomain.com
     ServerName yourdomain.com
     ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourdomain.com/public_html/

   <Directory "/var/www/html/yourdomain.com/public_html">
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<Directory /folder_name>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Its better to add a rule to allow your ip address. You can use **allow from your_ip_address** for this. Be careful with the ip address as it can be shared. You can check your ip address using http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: This neither works. I think that no .htaccess file is working. I have the next code in web directory and doesn't work in development mode (rewrite mode is enabled):                                                           <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

Comment: is the .htaccess file located in your root directory? If not, then move it to root directory and check.

Comment: Yes, it is in the web directory, where I have configured my apache to redirect when I put "itransformer" in the URL. Then, the web folder is opened in the browser, but not redirect to app_dev.php file. And the other .htaccess file (deny from all) is in other directory, which I want to deny.

Comment: I'm really confused... Could it be due to any apache configuration, that doesn't let to read an .htaccess file?

Comment: You may ask the hosting provider whether any configuration is required to execute .htaccess in the server? If not, then add some test code and see whether it works or not. You may report the same to hosting provider if that does not work.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use <Directory> in .htaccess