# .htaccess: Require all denied not respected

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've read a baker's dozen of similar questions and the common issues found therein have not helped me resolve this. I could really use some help figuring this out. What should I try next? Is there a way to troubleshoot why these rules are not being respected?

This is a Wordpress environment on an Inmotion Hosting vps with WHM/cPanel and Apache 2.4. Nginx is not being used to cache this account.

I need to deny access to PDFs in a sub-directory, specifically:

> /public_html/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/fillablepdfs/

My web root .htaccess is as follows.

**/public_html/.htaccess**

```
AllowOverride All

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I have tried many combinations in the web-root .htaccess and in the sub-directories in the path to the directory in question.

These did not work:

**/public_html/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/fillablepdfs/.htaccess**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

```
Require all denied
```

```
<Files "*.pdf">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

```
<Files "*.pdf">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

After those failed to work I moved up the directories attempting the same until I reached the web-root .htaccess again, where I tried the following.

**/public_html/.htaccess**

```
AllowOverride All
. . .
# BEGIN fillable-pdfs
# Restrict access to generated pdfs directory.
<Files "*.pdf">
    Require all denied
</Files>
# END fillable-pdfs
```

```
AllowOverride All
. . .
# BEGIN fillable-pdfs
# Restrict access to generated pdfs directory.
<Files "*.pdf">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
# END fillable-pdfs
```

```
AllowOverride All
. . .
# BEGIN fillable-pdfs
# Restrict access to generated pdfs directory.
<Files "*.pdf">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
# END fillable-pdfs
```

```
AllowOverride All
. . .
# BEGIN fillable-pdfs
# Restrict access to generated pdfs directory.
<Files "wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/fillablepdfs/*.pdf">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
# END fillable-pdfs
```

```
AllowOverride All
 . . .
# BEGIN fillable-pdfs
# Restrict access to generated pdfs directory.
<Files "./wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/fillablepdfs/*.pdf">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
# END fillable-pdfs
```

None of these worked.

There are two other .htaccess files along the path. They are:

**/public_html/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WebP Express
# The rules below have been dynamically created by WebP Express in accordance with the plugin settings
# DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY (unless you are prepared that your changes might be overridden by WebP Express)
# The following parameters have been in play to produce the rules:
#
# WebP Express options:
# - Operation mode: varied-image-responses
# - Redirection to existing webp: enabled
# - Redirection to converter: enabled
# - Redirection to converter to create missing webp files upon request for the webp: enabled
# - Destination folder: separate
# - Destination extension: append
# - Destination structure: image-roots
# - Image types: jpeg, png
# - Alter HTML enabled?: yes
#
# Wordpress/Server configuration:
# - Document root availablity: Available and its "realpath" is available too. Can be used for structuring cache dir.
#
# .htaccess capability test results:
# - mod_header working?: yes
# - pass variable from .htaccess to script through header working?: no
# - pass variable from .htaccess to script through environment variable working?: yes
#
# Role of the dir that this .htaccess is located in:
# - Is this .htaccess in a dir containing source images?: yes
# - Is this .htaccess in a dir containing webp images?: no

# Rules for handling requests for source images
# ---------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Escape hatch #1: Adding ?dontreplace to an url can be used to bypass redirection
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dontreplace$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # Escape hatch #2: Placing an empty file in the same folder as the jpeg/png which has same file name, but ".dontreplace" appended will bypass redirection
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
  RewriteCond %1%2\.dontreplace -f
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # Deprecated escape hatch: Adding ?original to an url can be used to bypass redirection
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} original$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # Deprecated escape hatch: Placing an empty file in the same folder as the jpeg/png which has same file name, but ".do-not-convert" appended will bypass redirection
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
  RewriteCond %1%2\.do-not-convert -f
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # Avoid redirecting to webp files that are bigger than the original
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?i)(/home/***/public_html/wp-content/uploads/)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
  RewriteCond /home/***/public_html/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images-bigger-than-source/uploads/%2%3.webp -f
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # Redirect to existing converted image in cache-dir (if browser supports webp)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?i)(/home/***/public_html/wp-content/uploads/)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
  RewriteCond /home/***/public_html/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/%2%3.webp -f
  RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ /wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/%2%3\.webp [T=image/webp,E=EXISTING:1,E=ADDVARY:1,L]

  # Redirect images to webp-on-demand.php (if browser supports webp)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
  RewriteRule (?i).*$ /wp-content/plugins/webp-express/wod/webp-on-demand.php [E=WE_WP_CONTENT_REL_TO_WE_PLUGIN_DIR:../../,E=WE_SOURCE_REL_HTACCESS:$0,E=WE_HTACCESS_ID:uploads,NC,L]

  # Make sure that browsers which does not support webp also gets the Vary:Accept header
  # when requesting images that would be redirected to webp on browsers that does.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "(?i)\.(jpe?g|png)$">
      Header append "Vary" "Accept"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>

# END WebP Express
```

**/public_html/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN Gravity Forms
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN Gravity Forms" and "END Gravity Forms" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
# Disable parsing of PHP for some server configurations. This file may be removed or modified on certain server configurations by using by the gform_upload_root_htaccess_rules filter. Please consult your system administrator before removing this file.
<Files *>
  SetHandler none
  SetHandler default-handler
  Options -ExecCGI
  RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
</Files>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule headers_module>
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</IfModule>
# END Gravity Forms
```

Comment: Do you actually have `AllowOverride All` in your `.htaccess` file as seems to be the case in your examples? Are you accessing these PDFs directly over HTTP?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, and yes.

Comment: `AllowOverride` is a server-only directive. It's not permitted in `.htaccess` (it doesn't make sense to include this in `.htaccess`). If you are not getting a server error (ie. a 500 Internal Server Error) then it would seem your `.htaccess` files are not being processed!? (Or perhaps you are on a LiteSpeed server and it's simply being ignored?) What kind of hosting do you have?

Comment: @MrWhite This is an inmotion hosting vps with WHM/cPanel.
I also tried the above solutions without ```AllowOverride```. There have been no 500 errors.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? Like I said, if you are using Apache and you weren't getting a 500 error with `AllowOverride` in `.htaccess` then it would seem `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled (ie. `.htaccess` files are not enabled) in the server config. `AllowOverride All` is a directive that needs to go in the server (or `<VirtualHost>`) config that enables `.htaccess` overrides along a filesystem path. Without this then `.htaccess` files do nothing (which is the default). But then this also begs the question, how is WP working? Are you using "pretty" permalinks?

Comment: in order to check if the root .htaccess file is being processed, you could just set up a test redirect, something like: `Redirect /foobar/ https://example.com` then test it navigating yoursite/foobar. If you don't get redirected to example.com, then the htaccess file is being ignored.

Comment: @MrWhite Apologies, it looks like AllowOverride did cause 500 error but _something_ was caching, so I did not see it. It is Apache 2.4.

Comment: @GrafiCode I have confirmed that your suggested redirect test is indeed working.

Comment: I think you should check your apache conf file, look at this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161758/htaccess-deny-from-all-doesnt-work

Comment: Providing you have the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive set in the server config - as noted above (it would need to include `AuthConfig` or be set to `All` for the appropriate file-path) then "some" of your attempts should work. Note that on Apache 2.4 you should not be using the deprecated `Order` / `Deny` directives. `<Files>` matches files only, not file-paths. If the mod_authz_core directives are still failing then you can resort to mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MrWhite That is a good idea. I tried ```<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(pdf)$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://[redacted].com/ [R=401,L]
</IfModule>``` but no dice.
I also took a look at the headers and noticed ```HTTP/2 301
server: nginx/1.21.6``` and systemctl shows that nginx is running. So even though it is not installed in WHM and disabled in the cpanel account, it is running. According to another dev, InMotion did some weird configuration with this server's nginx. Could that be interfering?

Comment: @GrafiCode So, followng your advice I dug into the conf, and it looks like AllowOverride All is set but I followed the directions in the virtual hosts section ```# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location   # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/[redacted]/[redacted].com/*.conf" ``` and created an include file with ```<Directory "/home/[redacted]/public_html/">     AllowOverride All </Directory>```. After rebuilding and restarting... it is still not working.

Comment: That mod_rewrite directive would block everything _except_ `.pdf` files. It should be a 403, not a 401. You should not enclose these rules in an `<IfModule>` container. Looks like you have an Nginx caching proxy? Where is Niginx 301-redirecting you to?

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for you help! I figured it out! There was an option buried deep in their custom nginx config tool "Accelerate static content", which it turns out bypasses apache even if nginx is disabled for the account... infuriating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx was configured to bypass Apache to "Accelerate static content".
Disabling this allows .htaccess files to function on .txt, .pdf, etc...