# Is there any security differences between using .htaccess and moving all files outside web root directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I am trying to decide whether to use .htaccess files in each sub-directory to deny all requests for specific files (while also denying directory indexes), or whether it is more security conscious to move all files except for essential files (index.php, .htaccess, robots.txt) outside the root directory and call them from the index file.

Are there any critical differences in security between these two methods for securing files in my web application?

Here is a view of what the .htaccess looks like in the root directory.

```
# pass the default character set
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|lock|DS_Store|json|)$">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# prevent display of select file types
IndexIgnore *.wmv *.mp4 *.avi *.etc
```

However, this would not stop someone from accessing a file if they knew the directory structure such as https://www.example.com/security/please_dont_look.cfg

Although that file does not print anything, I don't want anyone to know it exists, and don't want a site-specific solution like using modredirect to redirect calls to specific files.

I could use a .htaccess file in each directory such as this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

From this question and reply ([Prevent access to files in a certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046100/prevent-access-to-files-in-a-certain-folder))

Is one solution more bullet-proof than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in such complex systems, security here is about having several lines of defense, keeping things simple and attempting to prevent as many attack vectors as possible.

Theoretically both solutions should provide you with the exact same level of security - the files would not be accessible in either case.

I'd recommend moving files that should not be accessed directly into a directory outside of the web root directory. It is quite easy to screw up htaccess files and thats just not possible when you move the files outside of your webroot. This will also prevent timing attacks against the directory structure of your server: reading htaccess files comes with a time penalty and that might be measureable, especially if your htaccess files get big and you have plenty of them for each sub directory. Actually I'd recommend skipping htaccess entirely, just disable indexes directly in your vhost configuation, such that Apache does not have to look for htaccess files at all, speeding up your website.

Additionally, in case you run php via fcgi, you should disallow file access on a file system level for apache and just allow access from php. With this setup it should be outright impossible to access your files by attacking the webserver (excluding php) unless you have some privilege escalation vulnerability (in which case you are screwed anyways).

The only way to access your confidential files in this setup would be to convince PHP to read the file or to mess with the file system, i.e. by creating a hard link from your web root into your "confidential files outside web root"-directory. Preventing against that boils down to ensuring your PHP configuration is as restrictive as possible, file creation inside the webroot is disallowed and, most importantly, ensuring that the PHP application itself is not vulnerable.

Comment: Good comprehensive answer here, so I give you correct answer.  I will investigate how to you should disallow file access on a file system level for apache as you mentioend.  I assume by changing user:group for everything except the index file from _www:_www to something else that only php can read.