# How to block access to a static site?

Tags: html, github-pages, access-control, netlify, static-site

I will host a static site (just a few pages actually) on Netlify, a cloud hosting provider. It would be my notes and may have sensitive code and API keys. I want it set up so that only I can access this site from internet and no one else. How can I block access to the static site for others?

Alternately, if I do the same with with Github Pages, is it possible to restrict access there?

Answer (score 1):

You need an access control mechanism to protect your notes.

- If you are running the web server doing the hosting, most web server programs (Apache and nginx are the two most popular) have built-in access control mechanisms, see link given by Carsten H or see [Access Control with Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) or [How to Set Up Password Authentication with Nginx (Digital Ocean guide)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).
- If you are using Github Pages, it is possible to do access control, but a bit more tricky. You can create a Github OAuth application and ask people to authenticate using your Github OAuth app. The app will ask for their username, and check if that username matches a list of allowed Github users (probably just your Github username). If the usernames match, static content is served up, otherwise the user is redirected to a 403 forbidden page.

Also see the [github-heroku-attack-rabbits](https://pages.charlesreid1.com/github-heroku-attack-rabbits/) project page for details of how to create the Flask app mentioned above (using [flask-dance](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to authenticate users via your Github OAuth app). The Flask app can be hosted for free on Heroku.

Two more things to note regarding public/private repos:

- If you are using Github Pages, the repository containing your notes will need to be private, otherwise the contents of your notes will be in a public repository (even if the Github Pages static page has an access control layer).
- Just because a repo is private does NOT mean its Github Pages page is private. By default, a private repo's Github Pages page is accessible/readable by the public. It is up to you to put an access control mechanism in place to protect the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the encryption route. [Here](https://github.com/robinmoisson/staticrypt), the name staticrypt really says everything (I have a demo [here](https://yk-liu.github.io/secret)). It allows you to create a password for each page for your website. It used AES-256 encryption, so as far as I am concerned, a long password should suffice.

If you don't share the password, you will be the only one to view the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

These are actually two questions and is good practice to ask them individually.

1. This is a frequently asked question and depends on your server, e.g. for Apache you can edit your .htaccess following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046100/prevent-access-to-files-in-a-certain-folder)
2. you need to create a private repository by checking the private repository option during the repository creation