# prevent Access to Apache server web folder on EC2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

Hi I have built a web platform on EC2 with apache as my web server
I want to prevent access to my web folders
In case someone trying to do [www.mywebsite.com/include](http://www.mywebsite.com/include) or [www.mywebsite.com/includes/images](http://www.mywebsite.com/includes/images)
I want him to be blocked

I understood I have to create Htacces file with some rule
I have tried that with no success.
If someone have good knowledge Ill to have a tutorial in case the answer won't be enough
Thanks

I all ready described above

Comment: What were the htaccess rules you tried? This answer might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585118/10354667

Comment: If you don't want images available on the public web, don't put them into your webserver's publicly served directory. If they're referenced from HTML pages and embedded in the page, they need to be available - but if you don't like it you made the mistake by making them available in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directive **Location** or **Directory**, you can have more information on the Apache documentation: [Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/sections.html)
Below is the block code for Apache 2.4.X

```
<Location /include>
  Require all denied
</Location>

<Location /includes/images>
  Require all denied
</Location>
```